# Energy eigenstate of full Hamiltonian in interacting theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, vacuum

Does the energy eigenstate of a full Hamiltonian in interacting theory exist? Can we write $H|\psi\rangle = E_n|\psi\rangle$ where $H= H_0+ H_{int}$ ? I wanted to understand whether the derivation of eq. (4.27) of Peskin & Schroesder. Wont that violate the fact that time dependent Hamiltonian cannot have energy eigenstate (ref https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-06-quantum-physics-iii-spring-2018/lecture-notes/MIT8_06S18ch4.pdf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Hermitian operator has a set of eigenstates and eigvenvalues. As $H$ is Hermitian (even with the interactions) it also has such a set $H|\psi\rangle = E |\psi\rangle$. Usually, we identify these eigenvalues with the energy levels.

If $H$ is *time-dependent*, then at any time $H(t)$ has a set of eigenstates and eigenvalues $H(t)|\psi(t)\rangle = E(t) |\psi(t)\rangle$. However, usually this basis set and the eigenvalues will depend on time. The association of the eigenvalues with the energy in this case is more tricky, but the eigenvalues do exist.

Comment: Thank you, it does make sense. So can we say that there exist eigenstate but not energy eigenstate?

Comment: @Sakh10 If the system is not invariant under time translations, then energy is not conserved and not a good quantum number. It is therefore tricky to say that these states have 'definite' energy. But it is true that if we will look at the energy of the system at time $t$, defined as the expectation value of the Hamiltonian $E(t) = \langle H(t) \rangle$, these states will correspond to that energy.

Answer (score 1):

The full Hamiltonian for the interacting theory is not time dependent, just as the free Hamiltonian is not. It would become time dependent if one added an explicitly time dependent interaction, such as with some external time dependent field, but that is not being considered here. So yes, $H$ has energy eigenstates and those are what appear in that formula.

As an example, imagine some interacting theory that contains a stable bound state. That bound state is an energy eigenstate of the full Hamiltonian.